# SQLGrammarException: No value specified for parameter 1 with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

1-1 association:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "messageDetails")
public MessageEntry getMessageEntry() {
    return messageEntry;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public MessageDetails getMessageDetails() {
    return messageDetails;
}
```

Want to load dependent entry in stateless session:

```
    MessageDetails messageDetails =
            (MessageDetails) sess.createCriteria(MessageDetails.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("messageEntry", messageEntry))
            .uniqueResult();
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
```

The SQL is not what I want. May be I don't understand something?

```
03:21:13,274 DEBUG SQL:104 - /* criteria query */ select this_.id as id11_0_, this_.date as date11_0_, this_.messageId as messageId11_0_, this_.replyTo as replyTo11_0_, this_.subject as subject11_0_ from MessageDetails this_ where this_.id=?
```

I want to select MessageDetails by its property messageEntry, isn't that possible? Thanx.

Comment: What is that value of `sess`?

Comment: StatelessSession sess = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();

Comment: Can you provide us with the source code of `MessageDetails`?